# Matching searched digit-combination-pattern in string using regrex

Tags: r

I have a string `x` and i want to check if a digit starts with a letter and have less than 7 digits until the next whitespace or string-end. This is just one of much more strings in a datatable. There are four position-options for the searched combination in the string, see `toMatch`.

```
x <- '12345 ~ 23456 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345'

toMatch <- c("^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,5}[:space:]", "[:space:][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,5}[:space:]", "[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,5}", "[:space:][A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,5}$")

grepl(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), x, ignore.case = TRUE)

>>> TRUE
```

In this case the output is TRUE, but it should be FALSE, because the searched combination `A012345` has 7 digits and not less than 7. I think the script checks the first 6 digits and then it prints TRUE, but the string has more digits.

How can I say find a string-pattern with **6 or less** digits? I need a way without string split. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest splitting the original string by the tildes, testing your match against each substring, then only returning TRUE if all are TRUE.

Comment: I am searching for a way without string split.

Answer (score 0):

to modify the regular expression pattern to match strings that start with a letter followed by 6 or fewer digits until the next whitespace or string-end, you can use the following pattern:

```
toMatch <- c("^[A-Z]\\d{0,6}\\b", "\\s[A-Z]\\d{0,6}\\b")
```

You can then use the grepl function with the modified toMatch pattern to check if the string matches the pattern:

```
x <- '12345 ~ 23456 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345'
toMatch <- c("^[A-Z]\\d{0,6}\\b", "\\s[A-Z]\\d{0,6}\\b")
grepl(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

I took your example as a base, please test it.